Common practices for accessing OpenAPI spec for a REST API and JSON Schema for resources?
Is there a best/common practice for making metadata available for REST APIs, especially for APIs with available OpenAPI specifications?
For example, it was common practice to have a SOAP API endpoint support a ?wsdl query parameter to retrieve the WSDL document (metadata for the SOAP API) for a SOAP API.
Does OpenAPI specify (or are there best practices) where a client can retrieve the OpenAPI root document relative to the API base URL?
Also, does OpenAPI specify (or are there best practices) where a client can retrieve the JSON Schema for a particular resource?
